# Delete Product from Quote using WebService in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I have a Quote in CRM 4.0 and 4 products associated to it. Now I want to delete one of the product from the quote via WebService, can anyone please help me as to what entity instance should I use and how do I remove that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of a quote are defined by the entity [quotedetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928274.aspx).

> [quote] --- [quotedetail] --- [product]

To remove the line, you only need to delete the quotedetail record.